# Uniform convergence and series of expansion

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, uniform-convergence, laurent-series

Assume the following sum:
$$
s(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n \sqrt{n^2+x^2} \left(\sqrt{n^2+x^2}+n\right)},
$$
where $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Since $f_n(x) = f_n(-x)$, it suffices to consider $x \geq 0$. The functions $f_n$ are bounded by
$$
|f_n(x)| \leq \frac{1}{2 n^3} ~ \forall x \geq 0,
$$
this implies that $f_n(x) \rightrightarrows 0$. Because $\sum n^{-3}$ converges, it also follows that $\sum f_n(x) \rightrightarrows s(x)$ absolutely for $x \geq 0$. Since there is no closed formula for the sum, I am interested in series of expansion. At $x=0$ it works well, but I am struggling with series at $x=\infty$ . The naive approach gives
$$
f_n(x) = \frac{1}{n x^2} -\frac{1}{x^3} + \frac{n^2}{2 x^5}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^7}\right),
$$
which cannot be used as the first leading term goes as $1/n$ and it diverges in the sum (as well as the other terms). If I let Mathematica compute the plot, it looks like this:

[image: Numerical plot of the sum]

Of course, if I transform to $y=1/x$, then 
$$
f_n(y) = \frac{y^2}{n \left(n^2 y^2+n y \sqrt{n^2 y^2+1}+1\right)}
$$
and the data near $y = 0$ can be fitted, e.g.

[image]

or

[image]

but there are many fits which can fit well. 
I am looking for expansion of $s(x)$ for $1/x \ll 1$.
Is there an analytical way how to obtain the series? Is my approach correct?

Thank you for any advice.

**Edit**: for example, series of 
$$
\tanh(x) = - 1 + \frac{2}{1+e^{-2x}}
$$
for $1/x \ll 1$ is not polynomial in $1/x$, but it can be done in terms of $y=e^{-2x}$ at $y=0$, then
$$
\tanh(x) = 1-2 e^{-2x}+2 e^{-4x}+O\left(e^{-6x}\right).
$$
Ex. 2: this function has expansion (Laurent series) at $x = \infty$ in powers of $1/x$:
$$
\frac{1}{1+x^2} = \frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{1}{x^4} + O\left(\frac{1}{x^6}\right).
$$

Comment: What do you mean by **series of expansion**? To which order do you want to expand?

Comment: Expand function $s(x)$ for $1/x \ll 1$. E.g. is there a polynomial expansion in $1/x$? Or does it involve function such as $\ln(1/x)$?